# How to list the items that have been combined in a COUNT statement

Tags: sql

I have a DB that has two tables:
Table 1 has users
Table 2 has delegates of those users

What I would like to do in one query, if possible, is the following:

1. List the delegator UserID, pulled from the table with the users
2. Count the number of delegates the delegator has
3. List the ID's of the delegates

I have completed steps 1 and 2, but have no idea how to achieve step #3, if it is possible. Here is my query so far:

```
Select distinct users.UserID, Count(delegates) as 'Number of Delegates'
  From delegates
  inner Join users on delegates.delegates = users.handle
  Group by Users.UserID
  Order by Count(delegates) desc
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What output you get?

Comment: What type of DB is it? Oracle/SQL Server/MySQL? Whats the reason for having it all in 1 query?

Comment: -1 for asking a question that depends on the database system without naming your database system (and version). It's a nuisance.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
Select distinct users.UserID,
       COUNT(delegates) as 'Number of Delegates',
       GROUP_CONCAT(delegates.delegate_id SEPARATOR ',') as 'Delegate list'
  From delegates
  inner Join users on delegates.delegates = users.handle
  Group by Users.UserID
  Order by Count(delegates) desc
```

Comment: I forget that mysql has that function. mssql makes in-group concat such a pain!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the SQL-Server solution:

```
Select * From
(
Select users.UserID, users.handle, Count(delegates) as 'Number of Delegates'
  From delegates
  inner Join users on delegates.delegates = users.handle
  Group by Users.UserID, users.handle

) myTbl
Inner Join delegates d
on delegates.delegates = myTble.handle 

Order by 'Number of Delegates' desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have grouped by user ID you can not use Delegate ID in Select clause. 
One option that you have is to group by both userID and DelegateID, but the disadvantage is that same count would be repeated a number of times.

Comment: unless you use a subselect the count would be incorrect (likely 1 for each row in the result set)

Comment: Yes the count would not be as expected after modifying the group by clause. Thanks for pointing out.